# How to convert timezone in number to UTC?

Tags: python, timezone, utc

I have some random dates with different timezones, they are in formats like this `"07 Mar 2022 13:52:00 -0300"`, or they could be like this: `"07 Mar 2022 11:12:00 -0700"`. I don't know which timezone exactly they will be coming from. How can I convert all of them to UTC time `"0000Z"`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use standard module [datetime](https://docs.python.org/3/library/datetime.html) for this.

Function `strptime()` (`string parsing time`) can convert string to object `datetime` using matching pattern. For your examples works pattern `'%d %b %Y %H:%M:%S %z'`

Next you can use `.astimezone(datetime.timezone.utc)` to convert to `UTC`.

And later you can format string with `strftime()` (`string formatting time`) using again pattern `'%d %b %Y %H:%M:%S %z'` (or you can skip `%z`)

---

Minimal working code:

```
import datetime

data = [
    "07 Mar 2022 13:52:00 -0300",
    "07 Mar 2022 11:12:00 -0700",
]

for item in data:
    print('before str:', item)

    dt = datetime.datetime.strptime(item, '%d %b %Y %H:%M:%S %z')
    print('before dt :', dt)

    dt = dt.astimezone(datetime.timezone.utc)
    print('after  dt :', dt)

    print('after  str:', dt.strftime('%d %b %Y %H:%M:%S %z'))

    print('---')
```

Result:

```
before str: 07 Mar 2022 13:52:00 -0300
before dt : 2022-03-07 13:52:00-03:00
after  dt : 2022-03-07 16:52:00+00:00
after  str: 07 Mar 2022 16:52:00 +0000
---
before str: 07 Mar 2022 11:12:00 -0700
before dt : 2022-03-07 11:12:00-07:00
after  dt : 2022-03-07 18:12:00+00:00
after  str: 07 Mar 2022 18:12:00 +0000
---
```

Comment: Thank you for not resorting to pytz just to get the utc timezone offset, as many other answers to similar questions across StackExchange seem to.

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest to `import datetime`, then use the following method to convert your time stamps into datetime objects (where str is the time stamp as a string): `time_stamp = datetime.strptime(str, "%d %b %Y")` (where the parameter after str gives information on the formatting; for details see here: https://www.programiz.com/python-programming/datetime/strptime).

After that, you can use `datetime.astimezone()` to convert this into another time zone.